# RSockets are being deprecated at Flipper. Please, use the latest Flipper client in your app to migrate to WebSockets

Tags: react-native, websocket, flipper, fbflipper

In Flipper (v0.219.0) using React Native (v0.67.5) I am getting the following error in my Flipper app on MacOS:

```
RSockets are being deprecated at Flipper. Please, use the latest Flipper client in your app to migrate to WebSockets. App: phs. Device: iPhone Simulator.
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution in [this Github thread](https://github.com/facebook/flipper/issues/3554).

```
BTW: I've changed the FLIPPER_VERSION in gradle.properties to 0.138.0 and error disappears for now.
```

I updated my `android/gradle.properties` to:

```
FLIPPER_VERSION=0.219.0
```

And now the error is gone!